# How can we enable SNS logging for notifications sent to AWS Lambda using the SDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sns, amazon-cloudwatch

**Requirement:**

Enable SNS delivery status logging (to CloudWatch) for notifications sent to AWS Lambda using the SDK (not through console)

**Problem:**

Through the console we can easily [enable delivery status logging](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/troubleshoot-failed-sns-deliveries/) by selecting the protocol as "AWS Lambda". However, through the [SDK there is only an option to set it for the "platform application endpoint" protocol](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SNS.html#setPlatformApplicationAttributes-property), which has a mandatory property `PlatformApplicationArn` so it can't be used for other log protocols.

Is there something I'm missing, or is this feature not yet available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay so after a lot of hassle due to the documentation being **extremely** misleading, I've figured it out.

In order to enable logging for the Lambda protocol (and I haven't tested the others) you have to use [SetTopicAttributes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/api/API_SetTopicAttributes.html). Even though the documentation states that `AttributeName` is a map that contains `DeliveryPolicy`, `DisplayName`, or `Policy`, you actually have to set `AttributeName` to `LambdaSuccessFeedbackRoleArn`, `LambdaFailureFeedbackRoleArn`, and `LambdaSuccessFeedbackSampleRate` in **3 separate SNS.setTopicAttributes() calls**.

So, the parameters will look like this:

```
let paramsSuccessFeedbackRoleArn = {
    TopicArn: topicArn,
    AttributeName: "LambdaSuccessFeedbackRoleArn",
    AttributeValue: "replace with arn for SuccessFeedbackRoleArn"
};
let paramsFailureFeedbackRoleArn = {
    TopicArn: topicArn,
    AttributeName: "LambdaFailureFeedbackRoleArn",
    AttributeValue: "replace with arn for FailureFeedbackRoleArn"
};
let paramsSuccessFeedbackSampleRate = {
    TopicArn: topicArn,
    AttributeName: "LambdaSuccessFeedbackSampleRate",
    AttributeValue: 0
};
```

And then 3 SDK calls, one for each of the parameters.

Answer (score 3):

To complement @Deiv anwser, this is how it can be done in `python` and `boto3`:

```
client = boto3.client('sns')

snsarn='SNS topic ARN'

snslogarn = 'ARN of role that can write to CloudWatch Logs'

response = client.set_topic_attributes(
        TopicArn=snsarn,
        AttributeName='LambdaFailureFeedbackRoleArn',
        AttributeValue=snslogarn)

response = client.set_topic_attributes(
        TopicArn=snsarn,
        AttributeName='LambdaSuccessFeedbackRoleArn',
        AttributeValue=snslogarn)  

response = client.set_topic_attributes(
        TopicArn=snsarn,
        AttributeName='LambdaSuccessFeedbackSampleRate',
        AttributeValue='0')
```

Then to check if the attributes got set, one can use awc cli:

```
aws sns get-topic-attributes --topic-arn "SNS topic ARN"
```